# Error from Zookeper 3.4.6 version

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I downloaded zookeeper-3.4.6.tar.gz and while executing zkServer.sh start , I am getting below error.I did google but couldn't find a solution, Please let me kno if you see similar issues.

- CLASSPATH=/home/spanda20/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/home/spanda20/zookeeper/bin/../conf:
  **zkServer.sh: 81: /home/spanda20/zookeeper/bin/zkEnv.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")**

Comment: I have exactly the same version and I would say your install is broken, on line 81, I have `echo "Using config: $ZOOCFG" >&2`.
The md5 of the file is `dec17b86d0a345889b68233752999645` what is yours?

Comment: I didn't get your point. ZOOCFG is your config file rt.. Whats does echo "Using config: $ZOOCFG" >&2 mean.. Sorry can you pls put in details.

Comment: I'm talking about `zkServer.sh` in the `bin` folder.

Comment: Here is the value  and it matches..dec17b86d0a345889b68233752999645  zkServer.sh

Comment: @vanthome what do be done here..You have any resolution?

Comment: For me it works with just `./zkServer.sh start`. What is the default shell on the system you are using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. so its bash shell

Comment: How do you start it?

Comment: I just downloaded the zookeeper stable version and unzipped ..Modified the config file and then executed the zkServer.sh start. Is it related any sh and bash difference..?

Comment: @vanthome .It's worked .. I just restarted my vm and it worked out for me.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @user3858193 you should mark this as closed as it is already resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I am able to see storm UI and its running.
Below changes I did in the .bashrc file. Please make sure that You add bin path in the PATH VARIABLE.

I did add the below variables in the .bashrc file.

export JAVA_HOME =JDK Path
 export ZOOKEPER_HOME =Zookeper install path
 Then add them in the variable path.
 PATH= $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ZOOKEPER_HOME/bin

Thanks
Sanjeeb

Answer (score 2):

I'm using zookeeper version 3.4.9 on ubuntu 14.04 and installed openjdk 7. I have added below lines to `~/.bashrc`
`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"`
`export ZOOKEEPER_HOME ="/path/to/zookeeper"`
`PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin`.

First I ran `sh /path-to-zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start` but didn't not work I got the same error.

I ran it with `sudo /bin/bash /path-to-zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
./zkServer.sh start
```

This should work.

Edit `/etc/environment`, and paste the following:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

modify the `JAVA_HOME` as per your local Java version.